# Images appear to have a margin, but DevTools says it has none

Tags: html, css, image, image-gallery

I have multiple images that I split into 2 columns via `column-count` and I would like to try to display the images in a Masonry style of view.

I ran into the issue that the images have gaps in between them, I was able to remove the gap between images on their sides by changing the `column-gap` in CSS, but nothing I do can remove the game between the top/bottom of images.

Here is where I was able to recreate it: https://jsfiddle.net/dL4sjhf6/

And here is what it looks like: 
[image]

Comment: Use `display:block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add either `vertical-align: top;` or `display: block` to the images. By default, the images are inline elements which have some descender space at their bottom (i.e. under the image itself). Adding one of those settings will avoid that.

https://jsfiddle.net/3p4h0d75/